# How to add in spring boot project multiple local jars as dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have followings problem.

I should add a lot of local jars(more than 200 files) into my spring boot project as dependency.

So I dont want to have in my pom 200

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bla</groupId>
            <artifactId>testId</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried with

```
          <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <includes> 
                             <include>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/*.jar</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

In this case Intellij IDEA can see the jars, but if I compile the project in result jar there is only lib folder without my own classes from project and without files from spring boot.

I tried with this variante too:

```
 <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${basedir}/src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                        <include>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/*.jar</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I guess the problem is that the spring-boot-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin with "include" section dont work together.

My last try was :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${basedir}/src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
                        <include>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/*.jar</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I ask you don't suggest me to install the jars in local maven repository because I dont want to have in my pom.xml 200 dependencies.

Thank in advance

Comment: First, src/main/resources is for resources that need to be available at runtime. Not for libraries needed at compile time. Your issue is weird, and maybe we could advise something better if you explained us why you have 200!! dependencies, where they come from, why they are not in a repository, and why listing them in the pom as you should do is a problem. If you don't want to provide this information and you really think relying on local jar files is the best solution, then my advice would be to use gradle, which can use loops in the build script and is not limited by XML.

Comment: I would advise using gradle even if you didn't have that issue, BTW. It's just a much better build tool than Maven.

Comment: @JBNizet This comment does not help nor does it solve the issue...furthermore it is an opinion...

Comment: @khmarbaise this comment is a comment. Not an answer. It contains what comments are supposed to contain: an invitation to the OP to profide more details in order to be able to help better, and some alternative ideas to solve the problem. I don't see how that doesn't help. It surely helps much much more than your comment, which gives your opinion on my comment, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this plugins to add dependencies for building the project:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-jars</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${your_jars_folder}</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And you could add the folder to your project library settings for developing.

Comment: hi, correct me, if I am wrong. I tried this plugin, it adds the jars into local repository and I should add dependency of each jar in pom.xml self. Correctly?

Comment: hi @schroeder, you don't need to add individual jar to pom.xml. It will automatically lookup the folder and add dependencies when you use mvn package.
But for IDE, you have to add the jar folder to the library setting for developing. It works for me. Try to add that plugin and package your project.

Comment: jes, I have solved the problem with your solution. Thank you

Comment: What exactly is ${your-jars-folder}? Is it a full path to the directory with the local Jars? A path based on the project directory? How to you point to the directory with the local files???